# Java socket programming. How can i wait for server response in the background?

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to build a client/server program and it works fine. When i send a message it gets shown on the server and then it waits for a response from the server but i cant do anything while i wait for a response.

My question is : how can i wait for a response in the background while i can still send messages and just show the server message when it is sent(if it is sent).

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,UnknownHostException{

    // Specify remote address and port
    Socket cs = new Socket("localhost", 1337);
    // Input and Output
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(cs.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());

    // Writing message to the server
    String message = null;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        message = scan.nextLine();
        if(message.equals("exit")) System.exit(0);
        dos.writeUTF(message);
        dos.flush();
        // Check for messages from server ---> Here i wait for a message from the server but how can i wait in background without having my program freeze?
    }
}
```

}

Comment: its called threading. javas sockets are designed to block because you are supposed to run them in a different thread. in that thread you can wait and when soemthing comes you can return it to the ui (or console) by using some kind of eventlistener. in short: look up tutorials for multithreading in java

Comment: thanks for your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way in Java is to listen for server data in a separate thread.

Make the input stream final and insert something like this before the while loop reading from the console:

```
new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (true) {
        System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
      }
    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}.start();
```

This creates an anonymous subclass of `Thread`, which will execute the `run` method in the background when `start` is called.

When your code grows, you may want to implement the Runnable interface in a separate class and hand it in to the Thread constructor instead.

Comment: If this solves your problem, you may want to accept the answer (add the checkmark), so it doesn't remain open... Makes it easier to find questions that are still open...

Comment: just fyi (i don't think it really matters here): `System.out.println();` is not thread safe. i can potentially kill the jvm if called from different threads (that actually happend to me). With threads, thread-safety is always a concern, reading up on it won't hurt (much ;) )