# Java Socket Timeout although I can connect remote via Telnet

Tags: java, sockets, timeout

I am trying to connect remote host using Java Socket:

```
public class Socket3 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            //Socket soc = new Socket("192.168.69.169", 7772);
            Socket soc = new Socket();
            soc.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.69.169", 7772), 5000);
            soc.setSoTimeout(5000);
            BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter outWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(soc.getOutputStream()));
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Sending Data");
                outWriter.write("a");
                outWriter.newLine();
                outWriter.flush();
                String response = responseReader.readLine();
                if (response == null) break;
                System.out.println(response);
            }
        }
    }
```

Its getting read timeout. But When I try that same server from Windows telnet, its connecting and showing response properly.

In remote host is showing:  `Socket has been closed for SocketException. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

So, how can I keep my socket connected in remote till response is available, or how can I asynchronously read that remote response?

Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: Fixed this by following this post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751175/1887543

Comment: Windows Telnet does snot set a read timeout.